# What do the || and ⊥ symbols indicate when used as subscripts for vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I'm reading an article about an auto-encoder where the latent vector is "split up" in two vectors; one with the $\parallel$ subscript and one with the $\perp$ subscript. To be exact, their notation is as follows:

$\mathbf{z} = [\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}; \mathbf{z}_{\perp}]$

What is $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$ and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ and how do they construct $\mathbf{z}$?

EDIT: As people have pointed out, this question is probably better answered with some additional context. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.02968) is a link to the article. To quote the relevant paragraph:

GENhance is an encoder-decoder framework with a latent space between its encoder $(ENC)$ and decoder $(DEC)$ modules (Figure 2). The latent vector $(\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^{d_{z}} )$ of a particular input sequence $(\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{d_{x}} )$ is the output from the encoder module, i.e., $\mathbf{z} = ENC(\mathbf{x})$. In our experiments, $\mathbf{z}$ is the hidden state at the location of a  token (Devlin et al., 2018) that is prepended to the input sequence. Within the latent vector $\mathbf{z}$, representation relevant and irrelevant to the attribute of interest is stored in $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$ and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ respectively, i.e., $\mathbf{z} = [\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}; \mathbf{z}_{\perp}]$. To train the encoder to store information about the target attribute in $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$, we train it with a contrastive objective that aims to learn which of the two samples has the better value of the attribute:

$\mathcal{L}_{contrast} =−\log \left[\frac{1}{1+exp(\tilde{y}_{a} −\tilde{y}_{b})}\right]$, $\tilde{y}_{a} =f_{\parallel}(\mathbf{z}_{a\parallel})$, $[\mathbf{z}_{a\parallel};\mathbf{z}_{a\perp}]=ENC(\mathbf{x}_{a})$, $y_{a} >y_{b}$ (4)

where $(\mathbf{x}_{a}, y_{a})$ and $(\mathbf{x}_{b}, y_{b})$ are a pair of training samples, each containing an input sequence $x$ and its label $y$. $f_{\parallel}$ is an operation that maps $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$ to a scalar value. Here we use $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$ of dimension 1 and $f_{\parallel}$ is simply an identity operation.

Comment: Parallel and perpendicular components. Parallel/perpendicular to what? You’ll have to supply more context.

Comment: I have seen this notation for normalvector and tangentialvector, but I am not sure if this is the case here too

Comment: I have made an edit to the post. My apologies for not including more context in the original post.

Comment: At this moment I suspect that both $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$ and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ are vectors whose components are non-overlapping and subset of the components of $\mathbf{z}$. $\mathbf{z}$ is a latent vector encoding a sample $\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{z}_{\parallel}$ encodes a sample property of interest and $\mathbf{z}_{\perp}$ is a residual encoding of that sample. (Please forgive me for abusing terminology here, I'm not a mathematician).

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly some context missing here, but a reasonable possibility here is this: there is fixed vector $w\ne0$ and then $z$ is written as $z_{||}+z_\perp$, where $z_{||}$ is parallel to $w$ and $z_\perp$ is orthogonal to it. For instance, in $\Bbb R^3$, endowed with its usual inner product, if $z=(3,2,1)$, and $w=(1,0,0)$, then $z_{||}$ would be $(3,0,0)$, whereas $z_\perp$ would be $(0,2,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And my bad for not including more context. I've edited the post to include the paragraph as well as a link to the article. I'm missing any reference to a fixed vector $\mathbf{w}$ in the article.